# I can't locate and remove file in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, delete, locate

How to remove the unwanted chrome file rendering on my computer which I can't locate but is visible in 'Search your computer and online sources'? I have removed google chrome from my computer but this file still exists. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the file name you can use `locate <filename>` or `find -name <filename>`

But I think in dash you should be able to click on the file and see the file location by clicking `Show in Folder` button.